# Does a category method can extend to a subclass?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

```
@interface NSOutlineView (addations)

  - (id)selectedItem

@end

@interface AAAOutlineView : NSOutlineView
@end
```

So, Does the AAAOutlineView's object can invoke selectedItem method or not?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category methods apply to all objects of classes on which the category is defined. Since each `AAAOutlineView` is an `NSOutlineView` object, all category methods apply to `AAAOutlineView` objects as well.

Comment: But, This category is formal protocol. I tried about this situation that got "-[AAAOutlineView selectedItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10011aff0"

Comment: @CocoaUser You cannot call an instance method on a class. If you try `AAAOutlineView *someView = ...; id item = [someView selectedItem];` your code should work fine.

Comment: I'm really sure, I called it as instance method on an object. Maybe I mistake something.

Comment: @CocoaUser Another possibility is that you have not included the header with the declaration of the category in the .m file where the category is used.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to include header file in the .m file. thanks for helping